# Use xTensor to do the Ricci decomposition

Tags: physics, tensors, xact

I am new to xTensor. I would like to perform the Ricci decomposition with xTensor, but I do not have any clue. I want to replace the full expression $R_{i,j,k,l}=S_{i,j,k,l}+E_{i,j,k,l}+W_{i,j,k,l}$ into another expresion:

```
  eq = G[-p, -q] == Gdelta[-p, -q] - 1/3 x[i] x[j] RiemannCD[-i, -p, -j, -q] - 
   1/12 CD[-i][RiemannCD[-j, -p, -k, -q]] x[i]*x[j]*x[k] + 
   1/120 x[i]*x[j]*x[k]*x[l] (-6 CD[-i, -j][RiemannCD[-k, -p, -l, -q]] + 
      16/3 RiemannCD[-i, -p, -j, -s] RiemannCD[-k, -q, -l, s]) + 
   1/90 x[i]*x[j]*x[k]*x[l]*x[h] (-CD[-i, -j, -k][RiemannCD[-l, -p, -h, -q]] + 
      2 (CD[-i][RiemannCD[-j, -p, -k, -s]] RiemannCD[-l, -q, -h, s] + 
         CD[-i][RiemannCD[-j, -q, -k, -s]] RiemannCD[-l, -p, -h, s]))
```

How can I do this in xAct? because in the tutorials of xCoba I didn't find something like this.

Comment: If you have no luck on this site try here: https://groups.google.com/g/xact

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.